# How to search text throughout entire file system?

Tags: grep, recursive

Assuming that the grep tool should be used, I'd like to search for the text string "800x600" throughout the entire file system.

I tried:

```
grep -r 800x600 /
```

but it doesn't work.

What I believe my command should do is grep recursively through all files/folders under root for the text "800x600" and list the search results.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And by "it doesn't work" you mean exactly what?  Does it not print any output, hangs or print lots of `Permission denied` errors?  Did you run it as root or a normal user?

Comment: I'm getting some traction, first of all I was in my user home directory trying to run the command. So now I've cd / out to root. Next I tried the same command as above and I'm getting a lot of Permission denied errors. Ok, so now I try sudo grep -r 800x600 / and then I get a /proc/sysrq-trigger: Input/output error

Comment: Hmm, don't know why it wouldn't work. You may ignore access errors by doing `grep -r 800x600 / 2>/dev/null`. You can also try running it as root.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

I normally use this style of command to run `grep` over a number of files:

```
find / -xdev -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -H "800x600"
```

What this actually does is make a list of every file on the system, and then for each file, execute `grep` with the given arguments and the name of each file.

The `-xdev` argument tells find that it must ignore other filesystems - this is good for avoiding special filesystems such as `/proc`. However it will also ignore normal filesystems too - so if, for example, your /home folder is on a different partition, it won't be searched - you would need to say `find / /home -xdev ...`.

`-type f` means search for files only, so directories, devices and other special files are ignored (it will still recurse into directories and execute `grep` on the files within - it just won't execute `grep` on the directory itself, which wouldn't work anyway). And the `-H` option to `grep` tells it to always print the filename in its output.

`find` accepts all sorts of options to filter the list of files. For example, `-name '*.txt'` processes only files ending in .txt. `-size -2M` means files that are smaller than 2 megabytes. `-mtime -5` means files modified in the last five days. Join these together with -a for *and* and -o for *or*, and use `'('` parentheses `')'` to group expressions (in quotes to prevent the shell from interpreting them). So for example:

```
find / -xdev '(' -type f -a -name '*.txt' -a -size -2M -a -mtime -5 ')' -print0 | xargs -0 grep -H "800x600"
```

Take a look at `man find` to see the full list of possible filters.

Comment: Note that `-xdev` will exclude _all_ other filesystems, not just special ones.  (e.g., if you have `/home` mounted as a separate partition, it won't be searched.)

Comment: I tried running each one but both return an error -- `find: paths must precede expression: /`

Comment: @Level1Coder my mistake, I had the -xdev option in the wrong spot. I've edited the answer to correct this. @cjm Good catch, meant to say that but forgot by the time I reached the end!

Comment: Great, both are working now but I find that the first method is extremely slow. I ran both in 2 different terminals and the efficient one was done in ~1min and the inefficient method was slowly chugging along, I didn't even allow it to finish and just ^C out. Now that this works, is it possible to make it a bit more specific, such as only search text within files that are of filetype .txt, less than 2MB and modified within the last 5 days?

Comment: @Level1Coder, thanks for your comments. I've edited the answer to remove the inefficient version, since it's obviously rubbish :) And yes, it can be made more specific - again, I've edited the answer so that it covers your example.

Comment: @Richard, thank you for your excellent answer and concise explanation.

Comment: Note: When regular expressions aren't required 'fgrep' is significantly faster than 'grep', which will make a big difference if you're searching a large tree.

Comment: Note on @NathanKidd 's note: fgrep is deprecated, it's the same as `grep -F`

Comment: You can avoid going through `xargs` with maybe better efficiency by doing `find / -xdev -type f -exec grep -H '800x600' +`.

Comment: @Totor, thanks for the suggestion - actually my first version of this answer did that, but it turned out very slow on medium and large finds. Passing `-exec` to `find` will cause it to spawn a `grep` command for every single file it sees - creating then destroying thousands of `grep` commands this way kills performance. `xargs` starts fewer `grep` commands so has better performance.

Comment: No, the `+` sign at the end of the `find` command actually does the same thing as `xargs`: it spawns one `grep` process with several arguments.

Comment: I'm confused as to why you need the '(', ')',  and -a in this case.  Aren't the arguments given to find implicitly AND?   Regardless, I learned about these options!

Answer (score 17):

Normally you wouldn't want to actually search EVERYTHING on the system. Linux uses file nodes for everything, so some "files" are not things you would want to search. For example `/dev/sda` is the physical block device for your first hard drive. You probably want to search the mounted file systems not the raw disk device. Also there is `/dev/random` which spits out random data every time you read it. Searching that doesn't make a lot of sense. The `/proc` file system is also problematic in your case.

I would recomend one of two things.

1. Don't search at root, only search the places that might be useful. Search `/home` or `/usr` or `/etc` separatly. The info you are looking for is likely of a specific type, so it's likely to be in a specific folder anyway. Configuration settings should be in `/etc`. Your personal data files should be in `/home`. Limiting search to a major area like this will greatly reduce your problems with recursive greps.
2. Exclude problematic areas using `--exclude-dir` and a set of things you know you don't needlike this:
   `grep -r --exclude-dir /proc --exclude-dir /dev --exclude-dir /tmp --exclude-dir /lost+found`

Lastly, it's not uncommon to run across a few 'permission-denied' errors when doing a big recursive grep. In the normal course of use there are files your user may not be able to read. As long as these are just a few odd files and not things like the raw device for your hard drives or the entire proc file system, it's ok to just ignore the errors. In fact you can do this on the command line by sending all the errors into never never land:

```
grep -r search_string /path 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: `-I` to exclude binary

Answer (score 3):

For simplicity, I would suggest [ack-grep](http://betterthangrep.com/). Link shows many cases when `ack-grep` is a better option.

To use is, after install:

```
ack-grep pattern /
```

Comment: Thanks for recommending this, but I ran this and it didn't really give me the search results I anticipated. Seems like I will need to tweak many settings to get what I want. As of now Richard's answer works right out of the box. Will look into this in the future as it seems useful as well.

Answer (score 2):

Another way of looking at it is this way:

```
grep -r /* | grep "800x600"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you  want to run search for a text only in files matching a specific name pattern (e.g. `.txt` files) you can do:

```
grep -rlw --include="*.txt" -e "text to search" path/to/dir
```

Omit the `w` option if you also want to find files where the search text is a substring of the file content.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following (remind "sir"):

```
grep -sIr --exclude-dir={dev,proc,run,sys} "800x600" /
```

- `s` suppresses error messages like non-existent or unreadable files
- `I` ignores binary files
- `r` enables recursive search
- Sometimes `i` to search case-insensitive
- Sometimes `l` to display only the filename

Alternatively to search in all files except mounts (grep sadly does not have an `--one-file-system` option):

```
find / -xdev -exec grep -sIril "800x600" "{}" \;
```

Comment: Thank you sIr  .

Answer (score 0):

*then I get a /proc/sysrq-trigger: Input/output error

Your command is working. You are getting this error because you are trying to scan running processes for a string.

I recommend excluding system directories with

```bsh
grep --exclude-dir={proc,sys}  "800x600" /
```

Comment: according to [`man grep`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) it is `--exclude-dir=` with two leading minus

Answer (score -5):

simply right-

```
grep -r "800x600" /
```

-What is wrong in your current command is the quotes, "". Always put the string argument to `grep` in quotes.

Comment: This is not the problem here. You do not need quotes when giving this particular type of argument to `grep`. Try it and you'll see. Put the string "800x600" in a file and then `grep 800x600 file` and you'll see it works just fine. The OP is obviously having some other issue.